# OrderedDict with specific order in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I am sending to an API, and unfortunately the API requires the dictionary to be in a very specific order. I am loading the dictionary from a file.

Right now `json.load(fh, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)` does exactly what it's supposed to and orders the top level keys alphabetically, but I need the dictionary to be ordered differently.

Specific order:

```
{
  "kind": "string",
  "apiVersion": "string",
  "metadata": {...},
  "spec": {
    "subKey": "string"
  }
}
```

How do I specify the dictionary order of top and sub level keys with dictionaries that are loaded from a file?

Comment: JSON objects aren't supposed to be ordered, so you probably shouldn't use `json`.

Comment: @chepner I don't have a choice, it has to be ordered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, the order of the items in `OrderedDict` follow the same order that they were written into it.

So, if you want to control the order of the items when creating an `OrderedDict`, you can **write** them in the order you want. For an existing `OrderedDict`, you can **read out, delete and write back** each item in order.

In your example, if you need to adjust the orders of the items, you can do like:

```
orders = ("kind", "apiVersion", "metadata", "spec")
for key in orders:
    v = object_pairs_hook[key]
    del object_pairs_hook[key]
    object_pairs_hook[key] = v
```

Comment: Good point. Do you know how to write them in order after having read them?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Try writing some code using an OrderedDict and posting it with a specific question if you run into trouble.

Comment: This is pretty nasty, it's O(N), and that in native Python. The list comprehension approach is better.

Answer (score 3):

You no need `objects_pairs_hook` in that case, just load json file and create `OrderedDict` from it using custom sort:

```
SORT_ORDER = {
    "kind": 0,
    "apiVersion": 1,
    "metadata": 2,
    "spec": 3
}

d = json.load(fh)
d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: SORT_ORDER.get(x[0])))
```